# How do you copy cell by cell with Python xlwings from one file to another

Tags: python, excel, xlwings

I was using openpyxl but found it can not handle macro-based Excel files. I need to know how to copy certain cells from one excel file to another with xlwings, which can handle macros. The syntax is not the same and i am not sure how to go about doing that cell by cell accounting or rows and columns. Any sample code would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

for the ease to read and write data, you can use the below function to read and write

```
import xlwings as xw

   def readData(rownum, column_name):
        rownum1 = str(rownum) 
        cell = column_name+rownum1
        return sheet.range(cell).value

    def writeData(rownum, column_name, data):
        rownum1 = str(rownum)
        cell = column_name+ str(rownum)
        sheet2.range(cell).value= data
```

first make an object and open your excel file from where you need to read and write and define worksheet

```
wb_reader = xw.Book(path_file_ of_read)

sheet = workbook.sheets["Sheet1"] #for reading

wb_writer = xw.Book(path_file_ of_write)

sheet2 = workbook.sheets["Sheet2"] #for writing
```

and now just do

```
x = readData(2,3)
write(2,3,x)
```

Comment: @python_SAP if it solves your problem ,  an upvote or acception would be much appreciated.